# Search fields of registration

Tags: search

did the registration page in which the user enters the desired field to me, I try to search for these fields, use the search module api, but can not  find where I must to create a search field - for example, a user at registration indicates that he smokes in finding should be a line "smoking" yes, No (checkbox) - here I can not think of how it makes

Comment: Could you try to clean up language here? I suspect I have an idea what you mean, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: If you want issue to be solved. Please try to explain in detail.